# Paired sign and Wilcoxon tests with weighting

Tags: r, nonparametric, survey, wilcoxon-signed-rank, sample-weighting

In R, I am using the survey package (inverse probability weighting) to conduct these tests on paired data:

- Weighted Wilcoxon Signed Rank test
- Weighted Sign test

However, I am struggling in doing them.

By defining a design and then using the functions

```
signed_rank<-function (x) {sign(x) * rank(abs(x))}

summary (svyglm(signed_rank(variable) ~ 1, mydesign))
```

I have been able to conduct a non-paired weighted wilcoxon.

But I have not been able to conduct the paired version as well as the Sign test. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `wilcox.test (x, y, paired=TRUE) ` should do the job for you, with respect to Wilcoxon.

Comment: @jbowman yes but that Is not weighted

Comment: Your version of the non-paired Wilcoxon is not weighted either...

Comment: By "*weighted*", do you just mean a count of observations with the same value ?  Or is "*weight*" potentially a non-integer number ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I mean to use inverse probability weighting to balance the characteristics of the sample with those of the population

Comment: @jbowman yes as I am building the weighting design as follows

mydesign <- svydesign(ids=~1, probs=NULL, strata = NULL, variables = NULL,
                      fpc=NULL,data = my_data, nest = FALSE, weights=my_data$case_weight_new,
                      pps=FALSE,variance=c("HT","YG"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: to fix a code error

Your version of the signed rank test is probably not what you want, because the *rank transformation* doesn't account for weights.  This means the null hypothesis of the test depends on the sampling design; part of the point of design-based inference is to avoid this.

It would make more sense to compute the ranks the way `survey::svyranktest` does, as estimates of *population* ranks (there's a *Biometrika* paper cited in the references).  As far as I know, no-one has actually derived the null sampling distribution, but it's a reasonable guess that `svyglm` -- or, equivalently, `svymean` would produce something asymptotically correct. It does for the two-sample case.

For the sign test, you don't need ranks (of course).  The test asks whether the (population) proportion of positive and negative signs are equal, or in the paired case, whether the population proportion of the first and the second number being larger are equal

```
> svymean(~I((api00>api99)-1/2), dclus2)
                            mean     SE
I((api00 > api99) - 1/2) 0.34354 0.0318
> pnorm(abs(.34/0.0318),lower.tail=FALSE)*2
[1] 1.111631e-26
```

Assuming no missing values, the procedure for a signed-rank test of a variable `y` is

```
w<-weights(design, "sampling")
ii <-order(abs(y))
r<-numeric(length(y))
r[ii]<-ave(cumsum(w[ii]) - w[ii]/2, factor(y[ii]))
signedr<-r*sign(y)
svymean(signedr, design)
```

So, in the same example

```
> w=weights(dclus2, "sampling")
> dclus2<- update(dclus2,y=api00-api99)
> y<-model.frame(dclus2)$y
> ii<-order(abs(y))
> r<-numeric(nrow(dclus2))
> r[ii]<-ave(cumsum(w[ii]) - w[ii]/2, factor(y[ii]))
> signedr<-r*sign(y)
> svymean(signedr, dclus2)
       mean     SE
[1,] 2172.8 224.57
>  pnorm(abs(2172.8/224.57),lower.tail=FALSE)*2
[1] 3.836651e-22
```

It's not clear that the signed-rank test is very useful with weights -- it is not exact and need not be very outlier-resistant.

It would be reasonably straightforward to make these into functions that computed R `htest` objects -- it's just a matter of setting all the right names and attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much. This definitely helped me a lot. Sorry for my ignorance.
So I have to use the code in the first box for the sign test and the code in the last box for the signed rank test?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I've updated it for a coding error

Comment: Got it. Thank you again for your precious support